# Grails 2: Query about Grails Webflow

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails, grails-2.0, spring-webflow

I am using Grails 2.3.11. With the application Grails web flow is used.

The flow is there are four tabs, which will be treated as steps for Grails web flow. Clicking on a step it will go to list/search page. The first initial search will have default search parameter values. And at the same time it stores to the scope of execution's active session's scope.

Here is the code snippet.

`Object res = execution.getActiveSession().getScope().put(beanID, bean);`

Here `execution` is a reference of `FlowExecution`.

Later on this object is been retrieved using active session itself. Below is the code snippet to retrieve data.

`Object objectFound = execution.getActiveSession().getScope().get(beanID);`

In both the case `beanID` is same.

Now what happen to this is, when I put it to the active session, it does not gives error so assuming it is been saved properly. But on retrieving the object in another ajax request, retrieval of object gives null. Means no object found with the key.

Then strange thing happen is, when I perform search operation, same operation been performed as mentioned above. Now on retrieving with the same key it gives object back and not getting null value.

My query is why this is happening? How the web flow works in this case?

I think in both the cases it should give back the object against the key with which it is been inserted.

Let me know if require more information about the query.

Comment: I am a bit confused, why not just use `flow` scope? [webflow](https://grails.org/version/WebFlow/15)

Comment: The code snippet mentioned above is been written in another groovy class. It is not a part of Controller's action. From action, the flow is directed to gsp page, nothing else. From that page, through ajax call execution is been used to get values stored in execution's active session. And `flow` scope variable will be available in the controller only. So, it is not possible to use `flow` scope variable.

Comment: `execution.getActiveSession().getScope()` is equivalent to the flow scope, isn't it? It is treated as flow session scope. [Check this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.M1/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowSession.html#getScope()). It is for Spring Webflow 2.4, but I guess it will be the same in Spring Webflow 2.0 as well, which Grails 2 uses.